# Key being returned from database is different to the one shown

Tags: typescript, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I am trying to get the key that is generated by Firebase database when an Item is pushed to the database, however, the key being returned is of a different value. In the photo, you can see that the value for 'key' (-kqI0bxKg...) is different to that of the pushed object primary key. Why is a different key being returned (-kql0bxKgq...)? How do I fix this using angularfire and typescript?

```
  handler: data => {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(auth => {
        const currentUser = auth.uid;
        var myRef = this.afDatabase.database.ref().push()
        var myKey = myRef.key;
        console.log(myKey);
        var newEntry = {
            description: data.description,
            number: 0,
            createdBy: currentUser,
            key: myKey
        }
        this.afDatabase.list('whatIWant').push(newEntry);
    })
  }
```

[image: Firebase database]

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call `push()` a new ID is generated. Since you're calling `push()` in two places in your code, you're generating two separate IDs. To have the same ID in both places, call `push()` once and use the new reference in both places:

```
    var myRef = this.afDatabase.database.ref().push()
    var myKey = myRef.key;
    ...
    myRef.set(newEntry);
```